# Is there a library compatible with Hapi for fine-grained ACL / User permissions?

Tags: node.js, permissions, acl, user-permissions, hapi.js

Looking to use HapiJS as our API server. We need fine-grained user permissions, e.g. "User A can edit field B" "User C can view field D" for a given model / resource.

Before we start building something I've been looking to see if something like this has already been done that is compatible with Hapi.

Comment: Did you find anything?

Comment: No, that project is on-hold for the moment. Will post back here on any findings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've recently been working on an ACL project for hapijs. It should get you a good start. https://www.npmjs.org/package/hapi-authorization

Comment: Just checked the plugin, and I have a question - could you implement it in a way that user can have multiple roles, which are not hierarchical, but on a same level, allowing access to different parts of the application (let's say, manages_users, and manages_products)?

You could have a convetion that if user object has .role property, it's a single role; if it has .roles, then you expect an array and check against that

Comment: This functionality already exists and is the default. https://github.com/toymachiner62/hapi-authorization#plugin-config. If you have questions please submit github issues instead of posting on SO.

Answer (score 4):

I have just read an article where the ACL permissions are validated using the build-in scopes.

Here is the link to the mentioned article :
https://blog.andyet.com/2015/06/16/harnessing-hapi-scopes/

And to resume quickly (using the example from the above link), you get a user object that looks like so :

```
{
    "username": "han",
    "scope": ["door-trash-compactor"]
}
```

The scope can be generated by whatever is backing your ACL for this user.  In this case you have the resource `door` with id `trash-compactor` that can be checked like so :

```
server.route({
    method: 'GET',
    route: '/doors/{door_id}',
    config: {
        handler: function (request, reply) {
            reply(request.params.door_id ' door is closed');
        },
        auth: {
            scope: ['door-{params.door_id}']
        }
    }
});
```

The scope `door-{params.door_id}` will be translated to `door-trash-compactor` which will then be validated.  Han's request to the trash compactor door will be valid and he will get the `door is closed` message.

The blog post is well written (much better then this summary) and describes this in better detail - would recommend the read.